# adding incremented id attribute to all elements

Tags: perl, xml-twig

There is a XML-Twig example that shows how to add id attribute with incremented value to a specified element. Is there easy way to add incremented id to all elements.

```
#!/bin/perl -w

#########################################################################
#                                                                       #
#  This example adds an id to each player                               #
#  It uses the set_id method, by default the id attribute will be 'id'  #
#                                                                       #
#########################################################################

use strict;
use XML::Twig;

my $id="player001";

my $twig= new XML::Twig( twig_handlers => { player => \&player } );
$twig->parsefile( "nba.xml");    # process the twig
$twig->flush;
exit;

  sub player
    { my( $twig, $player)= @_;
      $player->set_id( $id++);
      $twig->flush;
    }
```

Comment: *Every* element, or every `<player>` element?  Your code is correct for the latter, though you might not want to overwrite an existing id.

Answer (score 0):

I'm going to assume when you say "every element" you mean it.  There's several ways you can do that via [`twig_handlers`](https://metacpan.org/module/XML%3a%3aTwig#XML%3a%3aTwig).  There is the special handler `_all_`.  Or since twig_handler keys are [XPath](http://www.w3schools.com/xpath/) expressions you can use `*`.

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use XML::Twig;

my $id="player001";
sub add_id {
    my($twig, $element)= @_;

    # Only set if not already set
    $element->set_id($id++) unless defined $element->id;

    $twig->flush;
}

my $twig= new XML::Twig(
    twig_handlers       => {
        # Either one will work.
        # '*'     => \&add_id,
        '_all_' => \&add_id,
    },
    pretty_print        => 'indented',
);
$twig->parsefile(shift);    # process the twig
$twig->flush;
```

Comment: Yes, thanks I meant every element automatically, since I would not know which elements are created, because script is converting doxygen generated perl module of C++ api, and there may or may not be public static method elements for example.